# Best way to store app settings that are configurable from administrator interface?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, app-config, configuration-files

In the admin interface of my application, the administrators can change global application settings that effect every user of the application.

But what is the best way to store/read those settings.

- Is writing a config yaml file from php a solution? (And how about caching?)
- Is storing it in a database (MongoDB) the best way to go?
  (Every request a query? Or serialize on login?)
- Is there a bundle especially for this? (Couldn't find one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `CraueConfigBundle` that adds a controller and a service giving access to a list of settings. It seems like it's tightly coupled to Doctrine ORM though: https://github.com/craue/CraueConfigBundle

Comment: I already found that bundle, i am making a fork for ODM as we speak!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you have two options, 
1) store it in file (i think better to store this in parameters.yml, than config files); But in this case, after each settings change, you'll need to clean cache;

2) store it in DB. If you'll have any performance issues using doctrine, you always have possibility to update getter/setter to cache results in memcache for example.

p.s. Both ways have own pluses. I prefer to split applications settings from its configuration options. So if admin wants to change global app settings, maybe it's ok to edit parametes.yml ?